# java sockets: multithreaded socket client get same localport number

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a multithreaded java socket client which posts http request to a java http server. I was searching the cause of rarely occuring communication problem, now I  found that on the client side two threads getting the same local port after establishing the connection, and on the server side when processing finishes for the request on this local port one of the thread gets connection reset error(other one finishes with success).
On the server side java.net.ServerSocket is used. 
On the client side java.net.HttpURLConnection is used.

My question is in which condition two different client gets connection to the same localport?
On client side every client thread has its own  java.net.HttpURLConnection, so cause should not be corruption because of multithreading. Also when I try this client on other than my server, no such error occurs.

Server Code:

```java
while (true) {
    MySocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = (MySocket)serverSocket.accept();
        System.err.println("request received ");
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        Work work = createWork(socket);
        try {
            getWorkManager().scheduleWork(work, WorkManager.IMMEDIATE, null, null);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error("Work not processed :: Local port: " + serverPort, e);
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        } 
    } catch (Throwable e) {     
        logger.error("Accept failed on socket:" + e.getMessage() +"  Local Port : " + localPort + " Server Port : " + serverPort , e);
        try {
            if(socket != null)
            socket.close();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Custom ServerSocket to be able to write log:

```java
public class MyServerSocket extends ServerSocket {

    public MyServerSocket(int i, int j) throws IOException {
        super(i, j);
    }

    public Socket accept() throws IOException{
        Socket socket = new MySocket();
        implAccept(socket);
        System.err.println("------->>>>socket localport opened :: " + socket.getPort());
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Custome Socket to be able to write log on close():

```
public class MySocket extends Socket{

public MySocket() { super(); }

public MySocket(String host, int port) 
    throws IOException {
    super(host, port);
}
public synchronized void close(){
    System.err.println("------->>>>port closed :: "+getPort());
    try {
        super.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("------->>>>error on socket close :: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Client side log:

```
    private void sendMultiThreaded() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(250);
            executor.execute(new SenderThread(++counter));
            executor.execute(new SenderThread(++counter));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
class SenderThread implements Runnable{
    int counter;
    public SenderThread(int counter ){
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        sendPost("SPMLOG_CALL_PROCEDURE~3092376387582~"+counter+"~3340003184406406~3917010108414~25~~24945169989630~25~ES~12433930256382~",counter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }

}

private void sendPost(String input, int counter) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://localhost:7033/FBWS/eigBagHttpDispatcher";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    try {
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CORE");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(input);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url  + "counter ::  " + counter);
        int responseCode =0;
        try {
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            printPort(con, "EXCEPTION --Thread ID:"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() +" :: counter ::" +counter);
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        printPort(con, "NORMAL--Thread ID:"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } 
    finally{
        if (con != null)
            con.disconnect();
    }
}

private void printPort(HttpURLConnection con, String message)throws Exception {
    Field http = con.getClass().getDeclaredField("http");
    http.setAccessible(true);
    Field serverSocket = http.get(con).getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("serverSocket");
    serverSocket.setAccessible(true);
    Field impl = serverSocket.get(http.get(con)).getClass().getDeclaredField("impl");
    impl.setAccessible(true);
    Field localport = impl.get(serverSocket.get(http.get(con))).getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("localport");
    localport.setAccessible(true);
    System.err.println(message + "  -- local port for request is :: "+ localport.get(impl.get(serverSocket.get(http.get(con)))));
}
```

And sample Output :

```
Server Side:
request received 
------->>>>socket localport opened :: 18980
------->>>>port closed :: 18980
******
Client Side:
NORMAL --Thread ID: 14  -- local port for request is :: 18980
EXCEPTION --Thread ID:18  -- local port for request is :: 18980
Unexpected end of file from server :: counter ::4
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:790)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:653)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1207)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at com.kasim.coreclient.CoreClient.sendPost(CoreClient.java:74)
    at com.kasim.coreclient.CoreClient.access$0(CoreClient.java:52)
    at com.kasim.coreclient.CoreClient$SenderThread.run(CoreClient.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Ps: I extended the ServerSocket and Socket classes to be able to log local port values. I was getting same error with the original classes.

Comment: This should never happen. Post some code.

Comment: Posted related parts. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing here that shows two clients with the same port at the same time.

Comment: have you seen thread id 14 and 18 having the same local port? Normally local port ids are incrementing by one for each new request.

Comment: I repeat. There is no evidence here of two clients with the same port *at the same time.* Your server log shows only *one* client. If you want to show two, you'll have to show two connections and their timestamps. But it isn't happening. All you're seeing is the effect of connection pooling. Your real problem lies elsewhere. And your claim that ports increment by one per request is baseless. They are allocated from the pool of free ports by the system in an unspecified way. And if there is connection pooling, a reused connection will have the same port number it always had, of course.

Comment: you are right probably there is some application level programming errors in some place. I will try to log timestamp and send it too. But my observation for normal ending requests are their localports are incemented and they have server side log too. but for errorneous requests this behaviour is changing. they are using same localport with a successfull request and getting error. My point is this errorneous requests never reaching server and failing. May be they are failing because of successful previous requests ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88923/discussion-between-cacert-and-ejp).

Comment: They are failing because they are failing. The classes you're using have been working for 20 years.

Comment: By the way I do not get any error if I set this jvm parameter. -Dsun.net.http.retryPost=true.